# Finding $E[\text{min}(X_1, X_2) | X_1<X_2]$

Tags: probability-theory

> Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent exponential random
>   variables with parameter $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, find
>   $E[\text{min}(X_1, X_2) | X_1<X_2]$ and $E[\text{max}(X_1, X_2) |
>  X_1<X_2]$.

I have no idea how to start with. Meanwhile, why shouldn't I have the following?

$$E[\text{min}(X_1, X_2) | X_1<X_2]= E[X_1 | X_1<X_2]=\frac1{\lambda_1}$$

One idea of mine is to further condition on the value of either one of the r.v., but it seems to lead me nowhere. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $P(A)>0$, then 
$$
\mathrm{E}[U\mid A]=\mathrm{E}[U\mathbf{1}_A]/P(A)
$$
for any integrable $U$. In your case,
$$
\mathrm{E}[\min(X_1,X_2)\mid X_1<X_2]=\mathrm{E}[X_1\mathbf{1}_{X_1<X_2}]/P(X_1<X_2).
$$

Comment: Thanks for replying. Would you please explain more on the term $\mathrm{E}[X_1\mathbf{1}_{X_1<X_2}]$? I am not familiar with this notation.

Comment: $\mathbf{1}_{X_1<X_2}$ is an indicator of the set $\{X_1<X_2\}$, i.e. it is $1$ for $\omega\in \{X_1<X_2\}$ and $0$ otherwise. Knowing that $(X_1,X_2)$ has density $f_{X_1,X_2}$ we have that $\mathbf{E}[X_1\mathbf{1}_{X_1<X_2}]$ is the integral $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} x_1\mathbf{1}_{x_1<x_2}f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)\,\mathrm dx_1\,\mathrm dx_2.$$